# Openapi/Swagger generation from Typescript code

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, swagger, openapi

I am looking for a way to **generate OpenAPI/Swagger API definitions** from code written in **Node.JS/Express.JS/Typescript**.

Ideally this would be just annotations the I had to my Express Typescript base controllers and this generate the OpenApI/Swagger by running some sort of command line, this way the API definition would always stay in sync with the actual implementation, and additionally this tool should generate some sort of middleware that can implement parameter validation of the controllers input parameters.

Thank you, kindly
  Oscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want swagger generated for you, you can make use of `NestJs`.
NestJs also provides inbuilt middle ware for validation.

If you wanna know more visit [this link](https://docs.nestjs.com/)